# Encrypt/Decrypt Json files in file system

Tags: java, json, encryption, cryptography

We have got requirement where we want to encrypt json files as well as other files formats(e.g. text , predominantly json though) , these files will be stored in the file system ( most likely windows) and will be moved using usb or some other media to batch processing system and decrypted there.

Please suggest us best practices for such requirement . I am researching on it and found about JOSE – JSON Object Signing and Encryption but just want to be sure before moving ahead.

Thanks
XslGuy

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about the proposed approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to be encrypting *files* rather than objects. That would largely rule out JOSE, as that is about encrypting / signing *objects* rather than files.

This seems like a prime candidate for PGP encryption. With PGP you can keep the private key on the back-office where you do the encryption and encrypt with a PGP public key. That way the encryption system doesn't have to know the encryption key.

There are many libraries and key management tools for performing PGP file encryption/decryption, which makes it easy to test the encryption/decryption.

For Java [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/index.html) would be a prime candidate. If you run into trouble the development mailing list of Bouncy Castle is the main source of information - search it first.

Comment: Yes , we want to encrypt files and copy it to USB/ external and move it to Back office and similar process we want to follow for moving data from back office to front office too. We will need encrypt/decrypt key for both offices , whether PGP will meet this requirement , another thing is that we want to read these json files using java code and process it , however  decryption should be applied on the fly instead of manually opening the message , whether PGP will meet this requirement ?

Comment: PGP can encrypt for multiple recipients and yes, PGP can be decrypted in memory. Bouncy Castle should be able to do this. Of course you would have to program this, but hey, this *is* StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, we are going ahead with Bouncy Castle , hopefully it will work .

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple encryption/decryption implementation without using third party lib. This is a blowfish implementation.

```
public static String encrypter(String value) {   
        try {   
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("My_Secret_Key".getBytes(), "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");   
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);   
            byte[] plainTxtBytes = value.getBytes("UTF-8");   
            byte[] encBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainTxtBytes);   
            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encBytes);   
        } catch (Exception ex) {   
            return value;   
        }   
    }   

    public static String decrypter(String value) {   
        try {   
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("My_Secret_Key".getBytes(), "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");   
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);   
            byte[] encBytes = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(value);   
            byte[] plainTxtBytes = cipher.doFinal(encBytes);   
            return new String(plainTxtBytes);   
        } catch (Exception ex) {   
            return value;   
        }   
  }
```

Blowfish is a symmetric-key block cipher. Read more about it [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29)

Comment: A cipher that the author has deprecated and ECB mode encryption, a key cq password that may differ across systems, the Sun internal base 64 codec, a plaintext that may differ because of the difference in encodings. Are you trying to get all the marks for bad encryption filled in on purpose?

Comment: "If blowfish cipher isn't present return plaintext". That's just **it**. Who voted this up I wonder?